# Create imagefield and set min width and height programmatically

Tags: 7, media

I've created an image field programmatically in Drupal 7. I want to set a minimum width and a minimum height on the image, so it checks whether the image is large enough.

The imagefield I've created:

```
$form['box_image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'media',
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#default_value' => isset($content['settings']['box_image']) ? $content['settings']['box_image'] : '',
    '#theme' => 'media_widget',
    '#media_options' => array(
      'global' => array(
        'types' => array('image'),
        'schemes' => array(
          'public' => 'public',
        ),
        'file_extensions' => 'png gif jpg jpeg',
        'max_filesize' => '500 KB',
        'uri_scheme' => 'public',
        // Can I set the min width and height here?
      ),
    ),
);
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. If you use Media browser, like me you could use:
`'min_resolution' => '750x500'`.